400 (Bad Request) when calling the Ajax wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
I checked all the similiar question but to no avail. Even chatGPt can't help now!
Anyways,
I'm using plain JavaScript to do a POST request to the WordPress backend so that I can work on the data.
This is my php code for creating the AJAX URL and the nonce.

 wp_localize_script('formalizer-js', 'formalizer_ajax_object', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('formalizer_nonce'), 
    ));

This is my function that's supposed to retrieve the data in the backend:
function formalizer_save_settings() {
// Enable error reporting for debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Log incoming request to debug
error_log('Incoming request: ' . print_r($_POST, true));

// Check nonce for security
if (!check_ajax_referer('formalizer_nonce', 'security', false)) {
    wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Invalid nonce.'));
    wp_die();
}

// Retrieve and process data from AJAX request
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true) : array();

// Log the processed data
error_log('Processed data: ' . print_r($data, true));

// Example: Save data to the database or perform actions
// For demonstration, log received data to error log
error_log('Received data: ' . print_r($data, true));

// Example response (adjust as per your needs)
$response = array(
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Settings saved successfully.',
    'data' => $data,  // Optionally send back processed data
);

// Send JSON response
wp_send_json_success($response);
wp_die();  // Always include wp_die() after sending JSON response
}
add_action('wp_ajax_formalizer_save_settings', 'formalizer_save_settings');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_formalizer_save_settings', 'formalizer_save_settings');

And this is my js:

const data = {
      servicesLabels,
      productsLabels,
      servicesInputs,
      productsInputs,
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(formalizer_ajax_object.ajax_url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          security: formalizer_ajax_object.nonce,
          action: "formalizer_save_settings",
          data: data,
        }),
      });

      const result = await response.json();

      if (result.success) {
        console.log(result);
        alert("Settings saved successfully.");
      } else {
        console.log(result);
        throw new Error(result.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      //alert("An error occurred while saving settings: " + error.message);
    }

Am I doing something wrong with the actions? Nonce?
Keep in mind the ajax URL is correct

You are sending a JSON request, so PHP will not populate $_POST, and WP will not be able to recognize any of your parameters. Do not send JSON, send a standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded request instead.
